# Is it possible to import OpenLayers data to PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, openlayers

I'm struggled with the following problem: I'd like to import an OpenLayers layer to PostGIS in order to have the layer information for each grid point in a table. I know how to create a layer from PostGIS tables to OpenLayers using GeoServer... but not the inverse way.

Please any help would be extremely appreciated

Comment: What do you mean by OpenLayer layer? Where is the data coming from? Is it a WMS or WFS or some thing else? Without these details, it will not be possible to answer your question.

Comment: Actually it is WMS layer, but I didn't knew it was important too. If so, which are the differences in any case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your data source is in a vector format (like WFS, GeoJSON, KML etc) then you can use [ogr2ogr](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) to convert and import the data.
Here is [an article](http://underdark.wordpress.com/2012/09/29/wfs-to-postgis-in-one-step/) which shows how you can put data from a WFS service into your PostGIS database.

If your data source is a raster format (like WMS, tiles, GoogleMaps Layers, Imagery layers etc) then you cannot get information from that datasource into your database.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it resolved my question and even more!